# Run runnable with properties (Jitsi)

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments, runtime.exec, jitsi

I wanted to create runnable jar of Jitsi, one of the most popular SIP communicator. So, I have packaged Jitsi as a runnable jar. It can be used when this runnable jar is passed appropriate VM arguments, like:

```
-Dfelix.config.properties=file:lib/felix.client.run.properties
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=lib/logging.properties
-Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_NAME=Jitsi-dev
```

My Main class which invoke this runnable jar with those parameters looks like :

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java", 
                "-Dfelix.config.properties=file:lib/felix.client.run.properties", 
                "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=lib/logging.properties", 
                "-Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_NAME=Jitsi-dev, 
                "-jar", "jitsi.jar");  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Of course in my jar you can also find those two properties files (felix.client.run.properties and logging.properties) in lib folder and also previously packed Jitsi in jitsi.jar. Unfortunately, I received an error that the config.properties via command line is not loaded. But when I make a shell script whuch runs jitsi.jar with the same parameters, I am able to run Jitsi. What is wrong with this above code ?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  As  an aside, that code looks like it would not compile, let alone run.  It is missing a closing `"`.  Don't waste people's time by posting 'something like' the code.

Comment: is there some reason you don't simply run your code against Jitsi itself?  Jitsi itself **is** runnable.